# Getting error in web.config: requirePermission is not declared

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, web-config

In my project i am was getting error:

```
error:requiredPermission attribute not declared
```

to resolve this i did google
    http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/forums/requirepermission-attribute-is-not-declared/p/1241/12676.aspx
 and then i found that i will have to add "xmlns" in my webconfig's configuration tag and i did that:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

but then i got new error:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0:configuration'.
```

and to resolve this i did google again and found a link:http://www.opcg.com/post/Could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-element-httpschemasmicrosoftcomNetConfigurationv20-configuration.aspx which is saying to remove that "xmlns" to get error resolved.

so both conditions become contradictory please help me and tell what should i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure with the assembly that you are using, but it seems it requires full trusted permission.

Please refer to this for how:  http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx

And this for detailed explanation:  http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302330.aspx

Hope this helps